# Select second 2nd child div from within the parents div

Tags: css

Hi I'm having problems selecting the second div from it's parent div.

Here is what I'm using:

```
.manufacturer_box div:nth-child(2){
 border-top: 2px solid #e0e0e0; 
 }
```

This is the output:

```
<div class="manufacturer_box">
    <div class="manufacturer_title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; width: 100%; line-height: 22px;">
        <span style="color: #999999; font-size: medium;"><br> 
        <span style="color: #333333;"></span> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you are trying to apply the css to this div: `<div style="border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; width: 100%; line-height: 22px;">`, it looks to me like it should work

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to remove inline style from the second div tag

```
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; width: 100%; line-height: 22px;">
```

It is overriding your css style.

For whatever reason if you want to keep the style, use !important although I highly DO NOT recommend this approach because it is very very bad practice but that's an option (however bad).

```
    .manufacturer_box div:nth-child(2) {
            border-top: 5px solid #e0e0e0 !important; 
     }
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct selector is use a child selector ">" to make sure that only the second  child div, of the parent div, will be selected. If you don't use > and only use:

```
.manufacturer_box div:nth-child(2){
    background: #FF0000;
    height: 200px; /* Manually set */
 }
```

This code is not specific enough, in the provided html will select "hello 1" and "hello 2" div's.

So the correct selector is:

**CSS**

```
.manufacturer_box > div:nth-child(2){
    background: #FF0000;
    height: 200px; /* Manually set */
 }
```

This will select only "hello 2" div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="manufacturer_box">
    <div class="manufacturer_title">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <div>
            <span style="color: #999999; font-size: medium;">hello 1 <br> 
            <span style="color: #333333;"></span> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="color: #999999; font-size: medium;">hello 2 <br> 
        <span style="color: #333333;"></span> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the snippet, remove the ">" to test that it selects multiple divs, and with ">" selects only the correct one.

```css
.manufacturer_box > div:nth-child(2){
    background: #FF0000;
    height: 200px; /* Manually set */
 }
```

```html
<div class="manufacturer_box">
    <div class="manufacturer_title">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <div>
            <span style="color: #999999; font-size: medium;">hello 1 <br> 
            <span style="color: #333333;"></span> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="color: #999999; font-size: medium;">hello 2 <br> 
        <span style="color: #333333;"></span> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the main goal is to override the border set in the inline style that you for some reason can't remove, I'd suggest to target it with attribute selector, not counting on the specific position of that div in the DOM:

```
.manufacturer_box div[style*="border-top"] {
   border-top: 2px solid #e0e0e0 !important; /* !important is necessary! */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline style from the second div.

Also, make sure the div has some sort of height. You can set this manually, or just insert some content.

**HTML**

```
<div class="manufacturer_box">
    <div class="manufacturer_title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="color: #999999; font-size: medium;">CONTENT<br> 
        <span style="color: #333333;"></span> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.manufacturer_box div:nth-child(2){
    background: #FF0000;
    height: 200px; /* Manually set */
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/439dx/1/